# golang exec command output empty

Tags: go, ncftp

I want run ncftpput in go and want to get the output string for analysis
but Only the following style can be output.

```golang
    cmdStr := "ncftpput -R -f C:\\Users\\xx\\source\\go\\depolyment\\cfg\\login.cfg / C:\\Users\\xx\\source\\go\\depolyment\\cfg"
    args := strings.Split(cmdStr, " ")
    cmd := exec.Command(args[0], args[1:]...)
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    cmd.Run()
```

I have tried many methods and the output is allways empty,such as:

```golang
cmd.Output()
cmd.CombinOutput()
io.Pipe()
```

Who can help me solve this problem, tks!

Comment: Have you checked the error value returned by `cmd.Run()` ? `err := cmd.Run(); if err != nil { fmt.Println("*** error", err) }`

Comment: for reference: the following code works as expected https://go.dev/play/p/uZkgNwHBLHB

Comment: @LeGEC tks, I have tried, the error is nil

Comment: please paste the code you wrote to run the command and get the `.CombinedOutput()` output of it.

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/ocClbwtzi9c     I guess Ncftpput is running in another process, so no information can be captured  @LeGEC

Comment: what is the output you expect ? a progress meter ?

Answer (score 0):

From the man page of ncftpput :

> `-v/-V`
>
> Do (do not) use progress meters. The default is to use progress meters if the output stream is a TTY.

Like many commands (`grep` or `ls` with their colored output for example),  ncftpput tries to detect if it is running in a terminal or not, and changes its default output based on that.

In a shell : try running `ncftpput ... > /tmp/output && cat /tmp/output` or `ncftpput ... | cat` to see what's the output when stdout is *not* a terminal (spoiler: it is probably going to be empty).

---

A command run in a `exec.Command` context is not run in a terminal context (its output is not a tty).

In your particular use case with `ncftpoutput`, if you want your progress meter output in all circumstances : just add `-v` to your command.

Comment: tks for your replay,  I added -v parameter, but output is still empty..

Answer (score 0):

My solution is add log file to ncftpput

```golang
package ncftp

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
)

type NcFtpPut struct {
    logdir    string
    loginCfg  string
    remotPath string
    localPath string
    debugFile string
}

func NewNcFtpPut(logdir, loginCfg, remotPath, localPath string) *NcFtpPut {
    return &NcFtpPut{
        logdir:    logdir,
        loginCfg:  loginCfg,
        remotPath: remotPath,
        localPath: localPath,
    }
}

func (n *NcFtpPut) Run() error {
    n.buildDebugFile()
    args := n.buildArgs()
    if err := n.execCmd(args[0], args[1:]...); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if err := n.analisysDebugFile(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func (n *NcFtpPut) buildArgs() []string {
    args := []string{"ncftpput", "-R"}
    args = append(args, "-f")
    args = append(args, n.loginCfg)
    args = append(args, "-d")
    args = append(args, n.debugFile)
    args = append(args, n.remotPath)
    args = append(args, n.localPath)
    return args
}

func (n *NcFtpPut) buildDebugFile() {
    n.debugFile = filepath.Join(n.logdir, "ftp.log")
    os.Remove(n.debugFile)
}

func (n *NcFtpPut) execCmd(cmdName string, args ...string) error {
    cmd := exec.Command(cmdName, args...)
    stdOut, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    errOut := hasOutput(stdOut)
    if err != nil {
        if errOut != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("%s:%s", err, errOut)
        }
        return err
    }
    if errOut != nil {
        return errOut
    }
    return nil
}

func hasOutput(stdOut []byte) error {
    if stdOut != nil {
        return errors.New(string(stdOut))
    }
    return nil
}

func (n *NcFtpPut) analisysDebugFile() error {
    buf, err := ioutil.ReadFile(n.debugFile)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    ret := string(buf)
    if strings.Contains(ret, "Operation successful") {
        return nil
    }
    return errors.New("error pls read ftplog file")
}
```